# Extracting human names from text in NodeJS, NLP

Tags: node.js, nlp

I am new to NLP using node js and I am trying to figure out NLP libraries that are available to figure out if a word is a human name in a given text.

Any help related to libraries or code samples or any ideas on how to approach this problem in nodeJS is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [compromise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compromise) NLP library — it can tag PERSON in a text. Note, no NLP library can offer you 100% accuracy!

Comment: Compromise works, but detection is questionable...

Answer (score 0):

you should try Named Entity Recognition(NER) Tools and Services
for example if you have this query:

```
Barack Hussein Obama II is an American politician
```

the result was this

[image: NER result]

for more information:

https://medium.com/@cloudmersive/how-to-perform-named-entity-recognition-ner-in-node-js-with-nlp-5862b44049b2

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

https://huggingface.co/transformers/usage.html